# how to initialize the prefix

Tags: python, bots, twitch

I'm trying to make a bot but I don't know how to remove the prefix so it can interact with everyone without having to type the '?' before every command

```
from twitchio.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        # prefix can be a callable, which returns a list of strings or a string...
        # initial_channels can also be a callable which returns a list of strings...
        super().__init__(token='...', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])
```

Comment: Did you try `prefix=''`?

Comment: yes but it does not work the bot goes online but does not reply to any command

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.